# Unity to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, php, sql, unity-game-engine, sqlsrv

I am trying to link my Unity project and SQL Server together with PHP. Currently, I am trying to setup the login credentials alongside user registration. However, Unity doesn't read the num_row function as shown below. Are there any other ways?

```
$loginID = $_POST["loginID"];
$loginName = $_POST["loginName"];
$loginEmail = $_POST["loginEmail"];

$sql = "SELECT id FROM testing WHERE id = '" . $loginID . "'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
  echo "Staff ID exists";
}
else
{
  echo "Creating user...";
  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO testing (id,name,email) VALUES ('" . $loginID . "','" . $loginName . "', '" . $loginEmail . "')";
  $result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql2);

  if($result1 == TRUE)
  {
    echo " New user has been created successfully";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }

}
```

Thanks guys!

I want to pull and push data between Unity and SSMS.

```
IEnumerator Register(string id, string name, string email)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("loginID",id);
        form.AddField("loginName",name);
        form.AddField("loginEmail",email);
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/UnityBackendTest/Register.php", form))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The issue currently is, it is not able to detect when I create the same credentials for the users and hence, the data is repeated. Hence, it did not read the "Staff ID exists" portion and in Unity, it says "Attempt to read property "num_row" on resource" @IShix

Comment: Yep. Tried it and it works fine @IShix

Comment: Yes it is correct @IShix

Comment: Done. Let me know if you need the full php code as well @IShix

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with all this code? Is this a PHP problem, or a SQL problem? Also be warned that your queries are widely open for SQL injection - have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: @NicoHaase everytime I run the code, the same user credentials will keep creating and hence, duplication of the same data happened.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: `$result->num_rows`... this should be producing an error in PHP. It's unclear if you've really done any effective debugging here, since you haven't mentioned that. sqlsrv doesn't have an object-oriented interface. [Read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php) to understand how to correctly write code to get the number of rows from a sqlsrv call. `$conn->error` will fail for the same reason. Again, [read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php)

Comment: And also read [this part of the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) to see how to pass parameters into your query instead of joining user data variables directly into the SQL string, which is very insecure. The first example in that documentation shows you the pattern you need to use.

Comment: `Are there any other ways`...yes. Reading the manual _before_ you start coding is always a good way. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php